# How can I change the function of the service now incident update action?

Tags: servicenow

Which ui action can I edit to change the behavior of updating an incident? I have looked through the ui actions and I can not find one for the update.

UPDATE: I was able to find the ui action for updating the incident. However when I try to edit it none of my changes are implemented. I just added an alert to it and nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question! The "Update" UI action can be disabled by creating a new UI Action, and **un-checking** the "Show Update" button on the UI Action form. You can then simply name your new UI Action "Update", and you're good to go! 
[image]